# Insert military time into a datetime column

Tags: sql

I have two columns of data for example

```
Row_Date    
2013-01-03-00:00:00

Starttime   
130
```

What i need is to take the start time and put this into a `date_time` column in the hour and minutes fields such as

```
Datetime
2013-01-03-01:30:00
```

All i can manage at the moment is to input the hour using the follwing command (this i found elsewhere)

```
,CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, StartTime/100, CONVERT(char(12), ROW_DATE, 112))
                                                       AS DATETIME) AS DATE_TOME
```

I can understand why this wouldn't work as its dividing the starttime by 100 which just leaves the hour and not minutes but i cannot figure out how to include minutes.

One other command i found but couldn't get to work was:

```
,CAST(CAST(row_date AS VARCHAR(8)) + ' ' 
 + STUFF(RIGHT( '000' + CAST(StartTime AS VARCHAR(4)), 4), 3,0, ':') AS DATETIME)
```

again this was found elsewhere but i get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Why are you trying to _format_ a `DATETIME` column? Format to string when you _display_, as the database will store it in some internal format.

Comment: Why is the `starttime` column's datatype integer and not time?

Comment: The starttime colum is coming from another data source (avaya) so annoyingly thats how it has come across. I guess it doesn't need to be formatted like that but still i need to include the minutes from the starttime, not just the result of starttime/100. Im starting to think i need to convert the starttime to a proper time format and then include this in the date_time colum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, 60 * FLOOR(StartTime/100) + StartTime % 100, CONVERT(char(12), ROW_DATE, 112)) AS DATETIME) AS DATE_TOME
```

Comment: Thats nearly there but not quite correct
Result
2013-01-03 02:48:00.000

Comment: its adding the minutes in, but, the output is like this 2013-01-03 02:48:00.000 this was when the starttime was 230 so instead of putting 30 in it has put 48 in. Really hate datetime calculations

Answer (score 0):

I had an existing datetime column persisting only a date (2022-01-01 00:00:00.000); the time part was stored in another column as a string in military format/numbers only (1359). This first thing I did was create this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_format_military_time(
    @chars VARCHAR(4)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(5) AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @work VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @return VARCHAR(5);
    SET     @work = '';
    SET     @return = '';

    -- no need to go further
    if (@chars IS NULL OR @chars = '')
    BEGIN
        RETURN @return
    END

    -- 9 -> 0009
    SET @work = right(concat('000', @chars), 4)

    -- 0009 -> 00:09
    SET @return = concat(substring(@work, 1,2), ':', substring(@work, 3,2))

    -- 00:09
    RETURN @return
END;
```

Adding the time part to the datetime is straight forward:

```
-- '2022-01-01 00:00:00.000' + '1359' = '2022-01-01 13:59:00.000'
SELECT datetime_col + CAST(dbo.fn_format_military_time(miltime_col) AS DATETIME) as datetime_col_now_with_time
```

Note does not work with datetime2 columns...